# ClassNotFoundException/NoDefFound on Runtime, but class imported works on it's own?

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to import a jar that I created to my project in Eclipse. When trying any calls from the so-called jar, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I believe this is caused due to the class being present on compile, but not being executed in runtime.

The problem is: When I run the jar on its own (without being imported), it works as intended, with all the functionalities. But I now need it to function as being part of a bigger jar, without changing the runtime classpath (didn't do that to the original project).

How can that be achieved?

**@Edit**

The class not being found or def not being found is ByteList, from the FastUtil library.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/bytes/ByteList

It's imported TO another Jar, let's call it MyJar.jar; MyJar.jar functions perfectly as a standalone jar, as the intention for it is to be a library, and it functions by itself.

The situation is: When I import MyJar.jar to another project, it won't work anymore, I can't use it's methods and classes inside the new project.

MyJar.jar can be run from the command prompt, with `java -jar MyJar.jar`, and it will print it's test-page to show that it's working.

The new project compiles, but when it's ran, I get the class not found exceptions regarding MyJar project.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Which class is not found? Which jar is it part of? And how do you run your application?

Comment: @JBNizet gonna edit it for furter clarification.

Comment: @JBNizet See if it got any better.

Comment: @MoisesCol.  What do you mean "it's imported to another jar"? Are classes (*.class files with corresponding package structure) into your MyJar.jar? Check it by opening MyJar.jar as simple ZIP archive.

Comment: *It's imported TO another Jar* what does that mean? You don't import jars to jars. That doesn't mean anything. What does MyJar contains, what is this "new project", and how do you run it?

Comment: I'm importing the completed jar of the other project, using eclipse, placing it in the classpath/buildpath

Comment: This other jar works as a standalone when I run it from the command prompt, and I need it to work when it's imported too

Comment: Putting a jar in the build path allows the **compiler** to find the classes needed when compiling your code. But those classes are still necessary at runtime. So the jar must also be in the runtime classpath when running the project. So if project A needs MyJar.jar, which depends on fastutil.jar, then 1.jar, MyJar.jar and fastutil.jar must all be in the runtime classpath when running a class from A.jar.

Comment: @JBNizet But MyJar.jar works without having fastutil on it's runtime classpath... How to get the same effect in project a?

Comment: If it works without fastutil in the classpath, then either the jar contains all the fastutil classes, or it actually desn't loadany class of fastutil. Since you still haven't said what the jar contain, and have posted no code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @JBNizet I think the jar contains the fastutil classes, and that way, it also contains when I import it to my new project, doesn't it? Then why it works as a standalone, but doesn't when I import it?

Don't believe the code actually helps anything, that's why I didn't post it

Comment: Instead of thinking, why don't you verify? A jar file is a zip file. Just open it and see. Or execute `jar tvf myjar.jar`.

Comment: It contains the fastutil jar, this containing all the classes.

Comment: Should I import fastutil again on the new project?

Comment: A jar can't contain another jar. That's not how it works. Eclipse allows doing this when the jar is an application, by also bundling a custom classloader, but that won't work as a standard library.

Comment: @JBNizet So I can't have the same jar both as an application AND as a sort of library?

Comment: And thus, I must import all the used libraries again in order to achieve what I want (exporting and using without changing the arguments to the JVM)?

Comment: Yes, you can,provided all the libraries it depends on are in the classpath. Don't embed a jar in a jar. Use the standard classpath mechanism, and everything is going to be fine. Please don't use the term "import", which isn't correct here. The alternative, that I wouldn't use because it sucks and causes all kinds of other problems,is to store the fastutil **classes** in myjar.jar.

Comment: What is the correct term then?

Comment: The correct term is "put a library in the compile or runtime classpath".

Comment: I used maven to organize my classpath in myjar.jar, and would expect it to work as a library, only to be referenced and packed into the jar... doesn't seem to work

Comment: I'm not sure,once again, of what you are asking, doing, and expecting here. Again, tell percisely how you run your application (i.e. post the exact and complete command), what exception you get (post the exact and complete stack trace), and post the contents of the jar(s) (i.e. post the output of jar tvf thejar.jar). If your question is about maven, then tell what you want to do, what your maven code is, and what it does instead of doing what you want it to do.

Comment: @JBNizet Added clarifications.

Comment: OK, so you're still using jars in jars, although I told you that it couldn't work. Don't.

Comment: @JBNizet Eclipse is doing that, not me... I'm just exporting the project

Comment: And it does work; The executable jar works...

Comment: Yes, you just watch eclipse doing it, you don't select any option, don't press any button? Don't make eclipse embed the jars in the jar. Choose the appropriate options. And I already told you why it works as an application: because Eclipse creates a custom bootstrapper class, using a custom classloader (the jarinjarloader package), to start your application. That won't work as a library. But I already told you all this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to add all classes from related JARs, otherwise you cannot load classes without adding them to classpath.

If you don't want to use Maven then add all needed classes manually to your JAR.

Comment: They're all inside the Jar which I'm importing to the project. The classes are there

Comment: How did you build your myJar.jar? See my comment to your question (it is fourth comment from the top).

I strongly recommend to use Maven Assebly Plugin as it works perfect in such cases. Otherwise you should to manually add classes to your JAR. I mean physical copy of class files to your Java ARchive!